# How can I store HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> inside a list?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, append

My hashmap stores the string as key and arraylist as the values. Now, I need to embed this into a list. That is, it will be of the following form:

```
List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>
```

These are the declarations I have used:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
map.put(key,arraylist);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Can anyone help me which method and how to use in the list to proceed storing my map into it?

Comment: you mean you need a list of maps of this form?

Comment: I assume you're using java and that most of your `(` should actually be `<`.

Comment: Yeah..its java.. Since '<' was not displaying correctly, i used '( '

Comment: Yeah.. a list that stores the details of my map... and retrieveing my list should display my map entires...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Always try to use interface reference in Collection**, this adds more flexibility.
What is the problem with the below code?

```
List<Map<String,List<String>>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,List<String>>>();//This is the final list you need
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();//This is one instance of the  map you want to store in the above list.
List<String> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist1.add("Text1");//And so on..
map1.put("key1",arraylist1);
//And so on...
list.add(map1);//In this way you can add.
```

You can easily do it like the above.

Answer (score 16):

First, let me fix a little bit your declaration:

```
List<Map<String, List<String>>> listOfMapOfList = 
    new HashList<Map<String, List<String>>>();
```

Please pay attention that I used concrete class (`HashMap`) only once. It is important to use interface where you can to be able to change the implementation later.

Now you want to add element to the list, don't you? But the element is a map, so you have to create it:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Now you want to populate the map. Fortunately you can use utility that creates lists for you, otherwise you have to create list separately:

```
mapOfList.put("mykey", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

OK, now we are ready to add the map into the list:

```
listOfMapOfList.add(mapOfList);
```

**BUT:**

Stop creating complicated collections right now! Think about the future: you will probably have to change the internal map to something else or list to set etc. This will probably cause you to re-write significant parts of your code. Instead define class that contains you data and then add it to one-dimentional collection:

Let's call your class `Student` (just as example):

```
public Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int studentId;

    private Colectiuon<String> courseworks = Collections.emtpyList();

    //constructors, getters, setters etc
}
```

Now you can define simple collection:

```
Collection<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

If in future you want to put your students into map where key is the `studentId`, do it:

```
Map<Integer, Student> students = new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
```

Comment: Nice answer, hope you don't mind I adjusted your code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
List<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> mapList = 
    new ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
mapList.add(map);
```

If your list must be of type `List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>`, then declare your `map` variable as a `HashMap` and not a `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define the `List` as :

```
List<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add the `Map` to the `List` , use [add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) method :

```
list.add(map);
```

Comment: That won't work given the current definitions of `map` and `list`.

Comment: I rolled back the edit on this post, due to a lack of comment by the editor or acknowledgement by the author.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student{
    //instance variable or data members.

    Map<Integer, List<Object>> mapp = new HashMap<Integer, List<Object>>();
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = s1.nextLine();
    int regno ;
    int mark1;
    int mark2;
    int total;
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    mapp.put(regno,list); //what wrong in this part?
    list.add(mark1);
    list.add(mark2);**
    //String mark2=mapp.get(regno)[2];
}
```

Comment: Some explanations about this piece of code would probably be beneficial.

Comment: Yes, for sure. Fact is i need a solution for the above could you clear it. By the next post i will properly explain the whole code.